# Complex LINQ Query with Groupings (need some help)

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Hopefully someone can help out with the following scenario. I have a table in sql, and I am trying to return all the records which match the value. That logic can have AND based on the group. For example

### Row ID Match Value Equal Group

1 >>>  1 >>>   1>>> a>>>    a>>>    1

2 >>>  1 >>>   a>>> b>>>    0>>>    1

3 >>>  2 >>>   a>>> a>>>    1>>>    2

4 >>>  3 >>>   b>>> c>>>    0>>>    3

5 >>>  4 >>>   a>>> a>>>    1>>>    4

In this case a 1 in the equal column means "equal" a 0 means "not-equal"

This data set after linqed would return records 1, 2, 3 because in row 1, a = (from column Equal) a
AND a != (from column equal) b. Rows 1 and 2 are "AND" because they are in the same group. So on so forth.

Thanks!

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entities? Something else?

Comment: linq to entities. i am pulling the data back using a stored proc in sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are getting at because your question is difficult to understand and it appears that your example data may contain a couple of typos.  However, I modeled something similar for you below.  Note I changed Row 1 because it looks like you had a typo, and I changed Row 5 so it would actually be an excluded case, otherwise you would have gotten everything.

```
public class Test
{
    public int Row {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Match {get; set;}
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Equal {get; set;}
    public int Group {get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var items = new List<Test>();
    items.Add(new Test() {Row = 1, ID = 1, Match = "a", Value = "a", Equal = 1, Group = 1});
    items.Add(new Test() {Row = 2, ID = 1, Match = "a", Value = "b", Equal = 0, Group = 1});
    items.Add(new Test() {Row = 3, ID = 2, Match = "a", Value = "a", Equal = 1, Group = 2});
    items.Add(new Test() {Row = 4, ID = 3, Match = "b", Value = "c", Equal = 0, Group = 3});
    items.Add(new Test() {Row = 5, ID = 4, Match = "a", Value = "b", Equal = 1, Group = 4});

    var result = items.GroupBy(i => i.Group)
                 .Where(g => g.All(t => 
                          (t.Equal == 1 && t.Match == t.Value) || 
                          (t.Equal == 0 && t.Match != t.Value)))
                 .SelectMany(g => g.Select(i => i));

    foreach (var i in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row: {0}, ID: {1}", i.Row, i.ID);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
Row: 1, ID: 1
Row: 2, ID: 1
Row: 3, ID: 2
Row: 4, ID: 3
```